# Apt-mirror - How to change mirror location without redownloading the whole mirror again

Tags: apt-mirror

I'm creating an Ubuntu mirror at a location with a lot of bandwidth.
I will have to move it to another country, where the closest mirror is a different one from the one I used before.

If I change my mirror.list file to point to a different mirror, it starts downloading everything again, due to the fact it creates a subdir for every mirror location.

If I rename this mirror location to the new mirror location, it still seems to try to download everything again. Is this right, or am I imagining this?

If so, how can I convince apt-mirror to only search for updates and not re-download the whole mirror again?

Karel

Comment: I've noticed that in all log- and index files under ./var are referring to my original mirror site. Should I change something in those files (rename the original mirror site for the new one in those files)?